# What is product obtained when B2O3 is reacted with NaOH?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Will the product be a metaborate ($\ce{BO2-}$) or a borate ($\ce{BO3-}$) or anything else and why?

Comment: Might be anything, depending on the conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ivan said, it may form metaborate, borax or a tetrahydroxoborate complex all depending on reaction conditions(temperature, pressure, medium, stoichiometry etc.).

1. $$\ce{B2O3 + 2NaOH ->[\Delta] 2NaBO2 + H2O}$$

Boron trioxide react with sodium hydroxide to produce sodium metaborate and water. This reaction takes place at a temperature of 400-550°C.

2. $$\ce{2B2O3 + 2NaOH → Na2B4O7 + H2O}$$

Boron trioxide react with sodium hydroxide to produce sodium tetraborate and water. Sodium hydroxide - diluted solution. Boron oxide is amorphous.

3. $$\ce{B2O3 + 2NaOH + 3H2O → 2Na[B(OH)4]}$$

Boron trioxide react with sodium hydroxide and water to produce sodium tetrahydroxoborate(III). Boron oxide is amorphous. Sodium hydroxide - concentrated solution. The reaction proceeds at room temperature.

Comment: Can't the product be NaBO3?

Comment: @Abcd NaBO3 requires borax and hydrogen peroxide. See this: http://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-sodium-perborate/